# NoClassDefFoundError on a JAR library included in Library Project

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror, library-project

I've created a `Library Project` which includes an `external jar-file`. This Library Project are referenced in another "App Project".

It can be compiled but has a run-time error

```
01-27 11:47:33.768: E/AndroidRuntime(12384): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.apprecommend_library.AppListFromCDNHandler
```

I have tried all the solutions but nothing seems to work. But think these solutions may be over a long time.

According to Android Developers, I also manually edit the App Project's build path and add a path to the JAR file, but it doesn't work.

How can I get this to work?

I've also tried:

check boxes in Order and Export

Java compiler level is 1.6

ADT version is 23.0.2

Comment: did you use proguard?

Comment: I didn't use proguard

Comment: In your `Order and Export` menu has your added jar file checkbox checked?? If it is not then enable that checkbox.

Comment: Yes, the added jar file is checked

Comment: I found only one class can not be found, why?